# Facebook API returning Uncaught Exception: 604: Your statement is not indexable

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently making an application that will read some post on my wall.
Problem is I keep on getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 604: Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql thrown in \application\libraries\base_facebook.php on line 1238
```

I already have those permission in the first place, I even added some other permission on my App settings. **read_stream offline_access read_insights**

AppId, secret and access_token are all set.

Update: Now the API returns a different error when I changed the query to this

```
$fql = "SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND created_time > 1346277600 LIMIT 50";
```

Update:
I now get this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 102: Requires user session thrown in \application\libraries\base_facebook.php on line 1238
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simply forgot to put the `access_token` at the facebook->api call

```
$data['posts'] = $this->facebook->api(array(
                   'method' => 'fql.query',
                   'query' => $fql,
                   'access_token'=>$facebook['access_token']
                 ));
```

Answer (score 4):

See :

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

There are only few fields which are indexable and hence one of them should be used in the `where` clause of your FQL.
Your query seems to work fine for me.

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20post_id%2C%20actor_id%2C%20target_id%2C%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20%3D%20me%28%29%20AND%20created_time%20%3C%201346647136%20LIMIT%2050&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE

Comment: I found the answer, but thanks anyway. If it werent for your all caps `ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE` I wouldn't notice the error in my api call. :)